# compile 64 bit under visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I have a 32 bit operating system and i am under visual studion 2010. I was wondering if i can compile a 64-bit MFC application with VS2010 under my OS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VS2010 has a cross-compiler in the vc/bin/x86_amd64 subdirectory.  It is automatically used when you add the x64 platform to your solution.  If you don't see it then re-run setup to add the 64-bit compilers.

You of course can't test it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am in the vc/bin/x86_amd64 subdirectory, what file should I look for exactly to know if i am able to compile a 64-bit application?

Comment: If the directory is there then that's enough.  Build + Configuration Manager, Active solution platform = New.  Pick x64.

Comment: I did that, but i still get this error : "32-bit version of Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor (msvsmon.exe) can not debug 64-bit processes or 64-bit dumps. Use the 64-bit version instead."

Answer (score 0):

In the Configuration Manager, add a new solution platform.  If you have the x64 compilers and tools installed, 'x64' should be listed as an available option.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can compile the code, but you can not run it. In order to run the code, you need to specify the run-time environment.